# Http GET response time

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, get

I have a Spring web application where I call Http GET on several URLs and udpdate the database with the results. My question is, how fast (or slow) can GET be?
Should I use second thread to perform this operation on a list of URLs and wait in main thread for this operation to complete? For example, if one of URLs do not respond (or is somehow slow) will that block my program? Or would it respond immediately with corresponding code?

Comment: There is an functionality in spring for async queries. [Asynchronous Methods](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/)

Comment: I know, but the question is: is it good idea/necessary in this case?

Comment: It depends on your use case entirely.If all the user actions that has to be done depends on the results obtained after these calls,then its a bad idea.But if there are other actions/tasks that can be continued independent of the results of these calls,then you can go ahead.Think from user's perspective.If your app's responsiveness can be improved by async calls then I would advise you to go ahead with this implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Remote I/O operations over networks with high latency (internet) are usually **slow**. If the remote service calls you want to access (GET requests in your example) are independent of each other, ie. you don't need one call's result to invoke another one, then it's quite easy/straightforward to introduce parallelism by enabling asynchronous processing. [Spring's async infrastructure](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/) could be a good candidate for this. If they are dependent on each other, it's a bit more complicated. You could use a programming paradigm called [Reactive Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming) and a corresponding implementation like [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjava). See [ReactiveX](http://reactivex.io/) for more details.

If you have many such calls to make over a request/request cycle it's definitely worth the effort in terms of response time performance.